# What type of Insect Egg is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, pest-control

Can you please tell me what type of insect eggs these are? I found them in the corners of my office kitchen behind boxes and cardboard. Found them in between the broom bristles. Found them along the edge of the wall. There are quite a few of them. 
If you could please provide me some tips on how to avoid getting these eggs or killing off the main insect would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I doubt they're eggs, but possibly larvae. Call an exterminator.

Answer (score 3):

These are probably cockroach cases, or oothecae, that may contain up to 50 eggs, depending on species.

[image]

It looks like they are oothecaes of German cockroaches.

You can read more about [baby cockroaches here](https://www.gardenlifepro.com/what-baby-roaches-look-like/).

Answer (score 2):

I think these are cockroach **oothecae.** These are small casings that contain many eggs.
[image: ootheca]
[image: dead cockroach with ootheca]

Quoting from wikipedia

> Female cockroaches are sometimes seen carrying egg cases on the end of their abdomens; the German cockroach holds about 30 to 40 long, thin eggs in a case called an ootheca. She drops the capsule prior to hatching, though live births do occur in rare instances. The egg capsule may take more than five hours to lay and is initially bright white in color. The eggs are hatched from the combined pressure of the hatchlings gulping air. The hatchlings are initially bright white nymphs and continue inflating themselves with air, becoming harder and darker within about four hours. Their transient white stage while hatching and later while molting has led to claims of albino cockroaches.[22]Development from eggs to adults takes three to four months. Cockroaches live up to a year, and the female may produce up to eight egg cases in a lifetime; in favorable conditions, she can produce 300 to 400 offspring. Other species of cockroaches, however, can produce far more eggs; in some cases a female needs to be impregnated only once to be able to lay eggs for the rest of her life.[22

You can find more about their control here

[Cockroach oothecae](https://www.pestwiki.com/destroy-roach-eggs/)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it's a fly chrysalis. If you had a mouse that died, that would do it. put them in a jar and wait. https://www.insectes-net.fr/pieride/images/pier159gf.JPG